# How can I pass an overloaded method-group as a single parameter?

Tags: c#

I know I can  pass a method like this:

```
Class A:
public void foo(Action<Class, Class, Class> bar)
{
    Class a;
    Class b;
    Class c;
    bar(a, b, c);
}
Class B:
public main()
{
    foo(bar);
}
protected void bar(Class a, Class b, Class c);
```

But I want it to be more conditional:

```
Class A:
public void foo(bar) {
    Class a;
    Class b;
    Class c;
    Class d;
    if(condition A)
        bar(a, b, c);
    else
        bar(a, b, c, d);
}
Class B:
public main()
{
    foo(bar);
}
protected void bar(Class a, Class b, Class c);
protected void bar(Class a, Class b, Class c, Class d);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: should one of the last 2 lines involve a 4th parameter? also: I suspect the word you are looking for is *overloaded*, not overridden. Different concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of passing a method-group (a set of methods of the same name but with different signatures) except by-name as a string, and then using reflection. Any `Delegate` / `Expression` / `MethodInfo` representation must be to a single method.

So: you cannot.

---

Suggestion:

```
interface IBar {
    void bar(Class a, Class b, Class c);
    void bar(Class a, Class b, Class c, Class d);
}
class YourType : IBar {
    void IBar.bar(Class a, Class b, Class c) {...}
    void IBar.bar(Class a, Class b, Class c, Class d) {...}
    ...
    public main()
    {
        foo(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other approach I could do?

Comment: @user maybe have one method, an `Action<Class,Class,Class,Class>`, and pass a `null` as the 4th parameter...?

Comment: Yes, I thought of it before. But this solution is as for this question . My current situation is more complicated. So I don't think this is probable for me.

Comment: @user1510539 in that case your best bet would be to declare an `interface` with the 2 methods you need, and change the parameter to be the interface. Delegates are *basically* a cheap way of declaring a single-method interface; but if you have multiple methods: you'll need a proper interface; see my edit

Comment: Hmm, I see... but how would the syntax of "foo" look like?

Comment: Oh! I get it. That would be foo( IBar k)! Just learnt new stuffs. Upvote!

Answer (score 1):

You could name the two `bar` functions differently, have two overloaded `foo` functions and move the condition from `foo` to `main`.

```
    protected void bar1(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a={0}, b={1}, c={2}", a, b, c);
    }

    protected void bar2(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a={0}, b={1}, c={2}, d={3}", a, b, c, d);
    }

    public void foo(Action<int, int, int> bar)
    {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 3;
        bar1(a, b, c);
    }

    public void foo(Action<int, int, int, int> bar)
    {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 3;
        int d = 4;
        bar2(a, b, c, d);
    }

    public void main()
    {
        if (condition)
            foo(bar1);
        else
            foo(bar2);
    }
```